# Ask page differs if you add slash at the end

Tags: bug, design

Adding a slash to the address of ask page changes page appearance:

> [image: compare]

In particular on the left picture ([no slash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)) vertical space between post part and the footer more than for page [with slash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/).

Related bug report on ruSO.meta: [Форматирование формы ввода и правки вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/176217)