# "Ask question" page doesn't look nice for unregistered users on sites with optional registration

Tags: bug, design, russian-stackoverflow

"Ask question" page on sites with optional registration (such as [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), [jaSO](http://ja.stackoverflow.com), [ptSO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), [rusSE](http://rus.stackexchange.com), [japaneseSE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com)) for unregistered users looks probably not very nice.

Here is screenshot of ["ask question" page on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

> [image: "ask question" page on ruSO screenshot]

Perhaps there should be some extra padding/margin to the right of `name` and `email` input fields (and maybe anywhere else)

---

Here are links to "ask question" pages on another sites: [jaSO](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), [ptSO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), [rusSE](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), [japaneseSE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (should be viewed without logged in)

---

Also, on [rusSE](http://rus.stackexchange.com) on ["ask question" page](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) input field with question title have incorrect width:

> [image: screenshot of rusSE "ask question" page]

(screenshots from Chrome 62 on Linux with incognito mode (that is without any extensions))

Comment: This also happens on another site, [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). I suggest you add this to your question, so that it doesn't get closed as "pertain[ing] only to a specific site".

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ is not a Japanese localization of SO, it's an English site for discussing the Japanese langauge.

Comment: @meagar, sorry, what is right name for sites which working language is not english?

Comment: @diraria I'm just pointing out that it doesn't belong in your list. The "ask question" page is entirely in English.

Comment: Wrong width of the input field for the title also described on [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/176217), that issue is related to another on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302866/339911).